# Why isn't my code running?

Tags: c

Im pretty new to C, but I need help on this

```
#define PISS 73
#include <stdio.h>
int a, b, c;
int killmeplease(int a, int b, int c);
int main(void)
{
    puts("WHATS YOUR AGE");
    //Gets int 'a'
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    int killmeplease;
        printf("Youre gonna die in %d years", b);
        getchar();
        return 0;


}
int killmeplease(int a, int b, int c)
{
    PISS - a = b;
    return 0;
}
```

Don't judge.
Not sure if this is just something I missed but whatever it it's its not letting the code run.
I may have put this in the wrong tab but if you can help thats great.

Comment: After preprocessing, this `PISS - a = b;` will be `73 - a = b;` which is not valid. What was it supposed to do?

Comment: You've already been told about [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What do you think the line `73 - 1 = b;` should do?

Comment: @13x it was supposed to take the users age and subtract it from 73 to see how many years they have left to live

Answer (score 2):

Although `73` sounds a bit early to die, this is how you can implement it :)

```
#define PISS 73
#include <stdio.h>
int killmeplease(int a);

int main(void)
{
    int a,b;
    puts("WHATS YOUR AGE");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    b=killmeplease(a);
    printf("Youre gonna die in %d years", b);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
int killmeplease(int a)
{
    return PISS - a;
}
```

The function returns the value based on the input `a`. You can also pass another pointer to it and store the return value from it.

You should also check the return value of `scanf_s()` for failure.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But I do remember doing it a different way, but this works.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do it. But this is probably the simplest way. You can also do: `killmeplease(a, &b);` and in the function: `*b = PISS -a;`., and change the function prototype and call appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe we could write functions and variables with sensible names and then mistakes might be more obvious:

```
void yearsOfLifeLeft ( int lifeExpectancy, int currentAge, int * yearsLeftPtr ) {
    *yearsLeftPtr = lifeExpectancy - currentAge;
}
...

yearsOfLifeLeft(PISS, a, &b);      /* 'a' and 'b' are names which are not good */
                                   /* and PISS is just childish */
```

Just an idea...